# How do I keep the links to the center right side of the screen no matter the size of the screen?

Tags: html, css

Here is the code for the question. I want the links on the right center side of the page to stay on the right center side of the page no matter how big the screen is on whatever device the person viewing it is on.

```css
.purplebox {
  background-color: #515151;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 50px;
  border: 3px solid #515151;
  float: center-right;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}
.greenbox {
  top: -100px;
  width: 100%;
  height: 500px;
  z-index: 2;
  text-align: center;
  margin: 150px 100px 30px 10px;
  float: center;
  font-family: 'Oswald', sans-serif;
}
.blog {
  top: -9px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 340px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 0px;
  border: 3px solid #ffffff;
}
.contact {
  top: -9px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 590px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 0px;
  border: 3px solid #ffffff;
}
.mybutton {
  top: -9px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 600px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 0px;
  border: 3px solid #ffffff;
}
.buttons {
  position: absolute;
  top: -9px;
  right: 430px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 0px;
  border: 3px solid #ffffff;
}
.bottom {
  background-color: #6d6d6d;
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 80px;
  right: 0;
  top: 883px;
}
.legal {
  top: -3px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -220px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 0px;
  border: 3px solid #ffffff;
}
.home {
  top: -3px;
  position: absolute;
  right: -70px;
  width: 200px;
  height: 0px;
  border: 3px solid #ffffff;
}
.picture {
  float: center-left;
  position: fixed;
  top: -25px;
  left: 50px;
  font-family: 'Secular One', sans-serif;
  color: #353535;
  font-size: 100%;
}
a:link {
  position: absolute;
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:visited {
  text-decoration: none;
}
a:hover {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
a:active {
  text-decoration: underline;
}
.large {
  font-size: 300%;
}
h1 {
  font-size: 250%;
}
```

```html
<meta charset="utf-8" />
<meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />

<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Oswald" rel="stylesheet">
<link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Secular+One" rel="stylesheet">
    <body link="#515151" vlink="#515151" alink="#515151">
<div class="purplebox">

  <div class="buttons">

      <p><b><a href="creations.html" target="_self">Creations</a></b>
      </p>
      <center>
  </div>


  <div class="mybutton">

    <body link="#515151" vlink="#515151" alink="#515151">
      <center>
        <p><b><a href="about.html" target="_self">About</a></b>
        </p>
        <center>

  </div>


  <div class="picture">
    <h1>A</h1> 

  </div>



  <div class="blog">

    <body link="#515151" vlink="#515151" alink="#515151">
      <p><b><a href="http://andrewdevs.tumblr.com/" target="self">Blog</a></b>
      </p>
      <center>

  </div>





  <div class="contact">

    <body link="#515151" vlink="#515151" alink="#515151">
      <p><b><a href="contact.html" target="_self">Contact</a></b>
      </p>
      <center>



        <div class="legal">

          <body link="#515151" vlink="#515151" alink="#515151">
            <p><b><a href="legal.html" target="_self">Legal</a></b>
            </p>
            <center>
</body>
```

Comment: The HTML you gave is not valid. For example, it's not valid to have `<body link="#515151" vlink="#515151" alink="#515151">` within a div. Are you perhaps using some framework?

Comment: Value "center-left" doesn't exist for CSS property "float".